# Confusion on MSAL.Net which one is correct implementation?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, adal, azure-authentication

```
I have refer this link
 
https://bnek.github.io/code/2020/09/17/Authenticating-SPA-with-msal-js-2.0.html

Its Implementation with MSAL is 

**## In this code we are not using AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi #**

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
  options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
{
  var instance = Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"];
  var domain = Configuration["AzureAd:Domain"];

  jwtOptions.Authority = $"{instance}/{domain}/v2.0/";
  jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
});

Now when I m referring another links #
```

### In this code we are using AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi

```
 var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            authBuilder.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration)
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()                       
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

so confusion here is which one is correct one ??
cos both code are associated with msal and with azure ad so which implemntation is more related to MSAL and why ?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) enables developers to acquire access tokens from the Microsoft identity platform to authenticate users and access secured web APIs. Both the implementations are using MSAL for authentication.

First one is using [Authorization with specific scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0) where application support multiple types of authentications and accept bearer token from several issuers. Authorization is this application will accept both authentication scheme.

Another one is using [AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebapiauthenticationbuilderextensions.addmicrosoftidentitywebapi?view=azure-dotnet) method to protect the API using scheme provided in configuration file with the necessary settings to initialize authentication options.

There are several ways to authenticate and authorize the users based on the scenarios.